# LINQ and handling rollbacks

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, error-handling, rollback

I have an image upload handler (.ASHX). I am storing image meta data in the database and am naming the image from the id of that entry into the database. I am using LINQ and getting the ID back after I call SubmitChanges. Then I use that id to save the image. I obviously want to rollback the insert if the File.SaveAs fails. Is my code below correct?

```
using (UserDataContext userDataContext = new UserDataContext())
{
    GalleryImage galleryImage = new GalleryImage();
    galleryImage.metaName = "some meta stuff";
    userDataContext.GalleryImages.InsertOnSubmit(galleryImage);
    System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = userClassContext.Transaction;
    userDataContext.SubmitChanges();
    try
    {
        string targetPath = "somepath/" + galleryImage.Id;
        file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is partially correct.

You, however, need to explicitly create a transaction before calling `SubmitChanges()`.

Comment: @Peuge: IIRC, you need to call `BeginTransaction()` from the datacontext's connection. Just try, it WILL fail if you are doing it wrong.